# Hide toolbar at focus EditText issue

Tags: android, xml

I'm using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in my application in a chat activity. But as soon as EditText focus and keyboard open, toolbar gets hide.

This is my xml code:
app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/myCustomToolBarTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ccc"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output Screens:

[image]
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know what is your problem I think that your layout is just moving up when you try to type something in this edit text. So my solution is:
Wrap everything besides toolbar in single layout and put in in scrollview.
Then toolbar will stay and content of page will be scrollable while you will be typing.
Try this code:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/second_activity"
            android:textColor="#000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:ems="10">

            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please post here a practical code.

Comment: Cold you tell me what is a problem? I exerted this code and it was working

Comment: Bro, same issue occur.

Comment: And sorry this is about list view not a normal view to set chat messages in list view.

Answer (score 0):

Just set,

```
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

in style.Then put the views under the scroll view.